# Configuring Python in Visual Studio Code on Windows 10

Tags: python, directory, visual-studio-code, pylint

I was working with Visual Studio Code and Python 3.7 installed in the default installation directory (\users\user\appdata\roaming), but when I updated my Python installation to the last version, "3.9.1", and after deleting all previous versions, I decided to install it in another directory (C:\Python), my Visual Studio Code does recognize my Python installation as you can see below:

[image: Python in Visual Studio Code]

But when running Visual Studio Code again, it tells me that Pylint isn't installed, logical since I deleted everything from the previous installation.

[image: Pylint]

The problem I'm facing right now is that when I install "pylint" it keeps installing in the default Python directory (\users\user\appdata\roaming) and telling me to add it to the "environment variables".

[image: Pylint installation directory]

How can I configure Visual Studio Code to install all libraries/modules in my new Python directory (*C:\Python*)?

Comment: Are you using `pip` to install python libraries ?

Comment: When using "pip" to install python libraries it installs them in the correct python directory `(C:\Python)` but when I install them from VS code they are installed in the wrong directory  `(\users\user\appdata\roaming)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An environment variable tells your system where the python.exe file is located. Pylint doesn't know where python.exe is. Use these steps:

1. Right-clicking *This PC* and going to *Properties*
2. Clicking on the *Advanced* system settings in the menu on the left
3. Clicking on the <kbd>Environment Variables</kbd> button on the bottom right
4. In the *System* variables section, select the *Path* variable and click on <kbd>Edit</kbd>. The next screen will show all the directories that are currently a part of the *PATH* variable
5. Clicking on New and entering Python’s install directory

Comment: I have my new python directory indicated in the environment variable.
The problem is that when VS code installs new python libraries it installs them in the old directory `(\users\user\appdata\roaming)`

Comment: Remove the old path from the PATH environmental variable